# How to add a side bar to main webpage using css

Tags: html, css

This might be a straight forward question however I cannot seem to solve this so any help welcome.

I have a webpage (fluidgrid layout), what I want to do is add a side bar on either side of the main page using CSS. I want to show the side bar on either side when the screen is bigger then 1300px. I would like these side bars to be as tall as the page is. Is there a way to do this using CSS.

**html**

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">Mainpage code here </div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width:981px){
.gridContainer{width:98%;max-width:1300px;padding-left:1%;padding-right:1%;margin:auto}
```

Any help welcome

Comment: Have you tried floating the sidebar to either left or right side? Then set height to be the height of its parent(the page)

Comment: I have tried to put the sidebars in with div's however they stay within the 1300px of the page I just want them to go on outside of the page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The ideas is simple, give the main container a fixed width and set the left and right margins to auto, that way, the left and right divs occupy the remaining space on each side. Then, add equal margins to the left and right of the sidebars. See example below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-sidebar">side bar content</div>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">Mainpage code here </div>
<div class="right-sidebar">Side bar content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:1300px)
{
   .left-sidebar  { display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; }
   .gridContainer { display:inline-block; width:75%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:1px solid black; }
   .right-sidebar { display:inline-block; margin-left:10px; }
}
```

Comment: I would like to sidebar to set their width auto so it evens out left and right and keep the gridContainer at 1300px. So for example when screen width is 1500 the sidebars on each side a 100 but this will be set automatically.

Comment: In that case, you set the .gridContainer to width of auto, and let the left and right sidebars fill the remaining space. Updating my code to reflect it.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, however this didn't work. I left the div's empty so the background color can take over (black). Only if you set a height for them it fills. The problem is it does fill the whole div from left to right so I ended up with a bar on the top and bottom. I just want to fill out the sides next to the page once the page exceeds 1300px. Thanks for helping

Comment: That's because a `<div>` is a block level element. To fix it, set it to display as `inline-block`. I assumed you already knew that. Anyway, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, that's not done the trick, the main page is now moved to the left with 10px margin (I presume) to the left. No auto fill with black to the left or right as I set the background-color:#000000;

Comment: I've updated my code, and tested it out and it works.